# I cannot add github repository to Julia as a package

Tags: github, julia

Could not able to add gitHub repo in Julia as a package as my code is using that package. It is throwing 404 error.

I don't understand why I am getting this error, so I would like to know any solution to this. By the way, I am using Julia 1.8 and on windows 11 machine

Comment: Is it a public repo?

Comment: also are you adding the https url or the ssh url?

Comment: Yes it is a private repo through Https

Comment: I think if you have ssh keys set up and use the ssh url everything should work. the problem is the package manager can't log in to GitHub for you.